# Is a static Application variable in c# a bad idea

Tags: c#

I've two Classes

```
   public class DemoProperty 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string MenuCode { get; set; }
        public string OriginalURL { get; set; }
     }

public class MyCommonProperties
{
        private static List<DemoProperty> _DemoList;
        public static List<DemoProperty> DemoList
        {
            get { return _DemoList; }
            set { _DemoList = value; }
        }
}
```

My need is to keep some common data throughout the project.For that I've using an application variable and it holds a `Dictionary<string,List<DemoProperty>>`.

Global.asx

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Application["DemoProperty"] = new Dictionary<string,List<DemoProperty>>();
        MyCommonProperties.DemoList= (Dictionary<string,List<DemoProperty>>)Application["CommonProperties"];
}
```

Actually I don't know more about its demerits. If it is a bad idea could you please suggest me a good one.

Comment: What is 'application variable'?

Comment: Which type of application is it, winform, webform, asp.net MVC?

Comment: What kind of application are you talking about?

Comment: Try searching... There's no golden rule "static is bad", it depends on how you use it.

Comment: @Libin C Jacob When your application is used by multiple users, that time it will be _bad_ idea to use. And the _value_ is common to all users, then go ahead..

Comment: See http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2009/01/static-variables-and-their-implications.html

Answer (score -1):

What the static keyword ensures, is that the specific property / class exists only once in your application.

If this is bad or not is a very general question to which the answer unfortunately seems to be "it depends". Ultimately it is a question how you want to design you program.

Making something `static` can however make automatic testing harder, because you can not easily decouple your program into smaller testable parts (as all parts directly interact with your static data). It also makes reading the code harder, because it could be hard to understand when and what modifies the global data.

I will try an example to underline this:

```
class Data {
    public static string Entry;
}

class Operations {
    void SetOne() {
         Data.Entry = "one";
    }
}
```

With this example, for someone calling `SetOne()` it might be non-obvious that the method actually sets something in `Data`.

Another approach could be:

```
class Data {
    public string Entry;
}

class Operations {
    void SetOne(Data data) {
         data.Entry = "one";
    }
}
```

Now for the caller its is more obvious that `Data` is used in some way by the method, because the call now looks like `SetOne(data)`.

In my humble personal experience `static` was almost never a good idea. While it might make things quicker in the short run, its drawbacks concerning readability & testability of your code are usually too big to ignore.

Comment: could the downvoter please explain what is fundamentally wrong?

Comment: OP's question is unclear, and there are already plenty of explanations for declaring a static class with static members on this site. _How_ isn't OP's question though. "Something like this" isn't a good answer either, it just presents copy-pasteable code that doesn't explain anything.

Comment: OP probably means an object with Application Variable, so the easiest way to accomplish his task is using a static class, rather than passing around an instance of a configuration object. How is this harmfull?

Comment: _"How is this harmful?"_ - it doesn't explain what the code does and doesn't explain the possible pitfalls of using static, which a proper answer should.

Comment: The question was not about how to use static, but whether it was a good idea to use it and if not, what the alternatives would be.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're right, I'll add more explanation.